# How can I Pass a specific jquery version to booststrap.min.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a widget type js application that gets embedded in many web sites. My widget uses its own jQuery and Bootstrap. Some of the websites also uses jQuery but of a lower version than the one I use in my widget.

To resolve the conflict between the two jQuery instances and making the website code unaware of my jQuery, I added the below simple logic:

```
// Backup websites jQuery objects
var websites$=$;
var websitesjQuery=jQuery;

var my$;

// Code for loading jQuery here...

function onjQueryLoad() {
    my$=$.noConflict();
    // Reverting jQuery variable objects to the one it was before loading my jQuery
    $=websites$;
    jQuery=websitesjQuery;
}
```

Now I want the bootstrap.min.js to use my jQuery version (saved in var my$). By default it uses the predefined jQuery variable. I want to do this because the website's jQuery is too old and is not compatible with the bootstrap.
I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the order in which you are loading your scripts.  You *don't* need any of this logic, in fact `$.noConflict` does most of this for you.

Try to do something like this

```
<script src="jquery_to_be_used_by_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="other_jquery_version.js"></script>
<script>
    // 'true' tells it to restore *both* `$` and `jQuery`
    // otherwise it just restores `$`
    var website_$ = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now, `$` and `jQuery` (the global vars) will be `jquery_to_be_used_by_bootstrap` and `website_$` will be `other_jquery_version`.

Since you can't edit bootstrap to tell it to use a different `$` (or `jQuery`) variable, you'll need to update your website to do so.

This can be fixed simply by doing:

```
website_$(function($){
    // Anything in here can use `$`
    // and it'll be from `other_jquery_version`
});
```

Demo of this concept: http://jsbin.com/dopomiyehu/1/edit?html,js,console

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rocket for the hint "**It all depends on the order in which you are loading your scripts.**", that solved my problem.

I put the bootstrap loader after jQuery load complete but before the $.noConflict()

```
// Code for loading jQuery here...

function onjQueryLoad() {
    // Code for loading bootstrap.min.js here...
}

function onBootstrapLoad() {
    my$=$.noConflict(true);
}
```